# How to display image with React Native and Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I'm making my first react native project, and I've used the create-react-native-app command to get everything set up. However, when I try to get an image to show up in Expo, it gives me an error message that it can't find the png file. I currently have the file under './img/record_video.png' (it's just an icon I'm going to use as a button). 
[Here's my project layout and the code I'm using to call it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeEQL.png)

That is, I'm using `<Image source={require('./img/record_video.png')} />` in order to call that file.

[This is the error message I receive on my phone from the Expo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwC9Y.png) In short it says `undefined Unable to resolve module './img/record_video.png' from C:\Users\ddude\Desktop\AwesomeProject\App.js':The module './img/record_video.png' could not be found from 'C:\Users\ddude\Desktop\AwesomeProject\App.js'. Indeed, none of these files exist:
*'record_video.png'
*'C:\Users\ddude\Desktop\AwesomeProject\img\record_video.png\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)'`

I'm not sure if it's that I'm using Expo and that it's not exporting to the phone properly, or if it needs to be in a specially-named folder. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the underscore & rename image assets to record-video.png, record-voice.png and convert-to-text.png. Restart the package manager and try.

> Just another observation I do not see an image record_audio.png in img folder
>   as required in second line.

Hopefully it helps.